# Ruby-rspec - how to print out the test (group) name

Tags: ruby, rspec

If I have some test, e.g.

```
  require_relative "Line"
  require_relative "LineParser"

  describe Line do

    it "Can be created" do
      load "spec_helper.rb"
      @line.class.should == Line
    end 
    it "Can be parsed" do
    ...
```

How can I print out the test group name - "Line" in this case.

I tried adding:

```
    before :all do
      puts "In #{self.class}"
    end
```

but that gives: `In RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3`, not `Line`

Answer (score 20):

You may have specific reasons for wanting access to the test name while you're in the test...however, just in case it fits your needs to just have the line output in the test report, I like this configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

   # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color = true

  # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
  config.tty = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation 

end
```

This gives me output like:

```
MyClassName
  The initialization process
    should accept two optional arguments
```

Comment: `config.formatter = :documentation` is what I was looking for.

Comment: `config.color_enabled` is now [`config.color`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/formatters/configurable-colors)

Answer (score 10):

RSpec will [read command line arguments from a file](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files), so you could add the following to a `.rspec` file in the root of your project:

```
--format documentation
--color
```

(This file may already exist depending on the gem you're using for RSpec and how you've installed it.)

Answer (score 8):

The answer turned out to be:

```
  before :all do
    puts "In #{self.class.description}"
  end

$ rspec line_spec.rb 
In Line
```

Comment: That's not really printing out the test name, though, is it? In your example, isn't it `Can be created`?

Comment: Perhaps I meant the test group name then?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm sure I'll be back here, this is what *I* want:

```
(byebug) $stdout.puts("#{self.class.metadata[:file_path]}:#{self.class.metadata[:line_number]}")
./spec/models/my_model_spec.rb:133
```